# How to get the value of the href attibute from element without having an explicit href attribute using Python/Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, href

I'm trying to get the URL link from an element with get_attribute('href') mode. However it returns **null**, like it didn't have href.

```
webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div/section[1]/div/a[1]').get_attribute('href');
```

If I click manually, or use `click()` function, it will get me to the URL of the button, so there is a hyperlink associated to that button.

The html code of the element is that below:

```
<a data-testid="subcategory-content-with-no-link" class="styles__baseSubCategory-sc-rqlxha-0 styles__SubCategory-sc-rqlxha-3 kLvfti hFicjq">Mastite</a>
```

How can I get the URL/hyperlink of that button using Selenium?

---

### Update

There's no href in any element inside `<div>` class as can be seen on this printscreen of html

[image: printscreen of html code].

Answer (score 0):

The html code that you posted shows that there is not `href` atteibute associated with that element. See if for example a parent element (possibly `div`) contains the `href` attribute instead.

**Edit**
As a workaround you can click the element to go to the url and get the url with `driver.current_url`

Comment: I add a screenshot on the post so you can see there's no href

Comment: I edited my answer to suggest a workaround solution, though it might not be optimal for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Though on clicking the desired element you will be redirect to the desired *URL* but the *`href`* attribute is absent can be easily acknowledged from the value of the *`data-testid`* set as ***subcategory-content-with-no-link***.

However, it needs to be emphasized that the *`href`* attribute is obfuscated within the ***class*** attribute value:

```
class="styles__baseSubCategory-sc-rqlxha-0 styles__SubCategory-sc-rqlxha-3 kLvfti hFicjq"
```